# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте проблема, консоль говорит *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )* 
вот код:

```
$.each(content.data, function(index,content.data){ // это строке ошибка
  //
});
```

UPD:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var num = 12;
   var inProcess = false;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() && !inProcess)
      {
         $.ajax({
            url: "/load.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {"num" : num},
            beforeSend: function() {
               inProcess = true;
            }

            }).done(function(data) {
               content = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               if (content.status == "success")
               {
                  if (content.data.length > 0)
                  {
                     $.each(content.data, function(index, item){
                        console.log(item);
                     });
                     inProcess = false;
                     num+=12;
                  }
               }
            });

      }else {

      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(content.data, function(index, item){

});
```

Comment: @Artem Ryzhov, спасибо, но теперь ещё одна появилась:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a

Comment: @Алексей, очень странно, у меня работает ) может где-то еще ошибка?

Comment: ошибка в файле jquery, вот что говорит консоль:

jquery.js:550

Comment: @Artem Ryzhov, я добавил весь код в вопрос

Comment: @Алексей
> content = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
Мне кажется здесь не валидный json... проверьте что приходит с сервера...